# time-column cleanup with substitutions

Tags: r

I'm probably working with one of the craziest databases in the world, and I need to format exported time columns for a report. The problem is, the times in this column is imported from multiple sources, some with proper sql date format (2017-03-01 01:45:00.000), and some with the date set to server default, with only the time properly recorded (1900-01-01 00:45:00.000).

For example:

```
df$Date = c("2017-02-01 00:00:00.000", "2017-03-01 00:00:00.000", "2017-01-01 00:00:00.000")
df$Time = c("1900-01-01 03:30:00.000", "2017-03-01 04:45:00.000", "1900-01-01 05:50:00.000")
```

I need a result of:

```
properdatetime<- c("2017-02-01 03:30:00.000", "2017-03-01 04:45:00.000", "2017-01-01 05:50:00.000" )
```

I tried a mixture of chron & gsub, but no dice:

```
library(chron)
tmp <- c(df$Date)
tmp<-gsub('$.{1}', '', tmp2)

tmp2 <- c(df$Time)
tmp2<-gsub('^.{1}$', '', tmp2) #regex - keep last portion of column

df$properdatetime<- chron(dates.=tmp,times.=tmp2, format=c('y-m-d','h:m:s'))
```

I keep getting this error:

```
'Error in convert.dates(dates., format = format[[1]], origin. = origin.) : 
  format y-m-d may be incorrect'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically used the `regmatches` + `gregexpr` combo to extract the dates from `Date` and times from `Time` and concatenated them to create `propDateTime`

```
Date = c("2017-02-01 00:00:00.000", "2017-03-01 00:00:00.000", "2017-01-01 00:00:00.000") 
Time = c("1900-01-01 03:30:00.000", "2017-03-01 04:45:00.000", "1900-01-01 05:50:00.000")

Dates = regmatches(Date, gregexpr("^[[:digit:][:punct:]]+\\>", Date))
Times = regmatches(Time, gregexpr("\\<[[:digit:][:punct:]]+$", Time))

propDateTime = paste(Dates, Times)
propDateTime = as.POSIXct(propDateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# "2017-02-01 03:30:00 EST" "2017-03-01 04:45:00 EST" "2017-01-01 05:50:00 EST"
```

Here I used a `as.POSIXct` to store the data as a "DateTime" object, which preserves the hours, minutes and seconds. Notice that the datetime created is in the EST time zone. You can use the `zone =` argument to specify a difference time zone if it makes a difference.

Comment: thanks for your help- When I ran the folowing, I recived this error "Error in `Encoding<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "bytes") : 
  a character vector argument expected"  - is that a Regex issue?

Comment: @rattacat There shouldn't be an error. Try clearing your work space and re-running the code.

Comment: Cleared twice. When I ran it line by line, it works fine on the "Dates" column, but it does on the "Times" column, producing that error.

Comment: @rattacat The error seems to be saying that your `Time` variable is not a character vector. Did you use the `Time` variable I created, or did you use your own? For the latter, can you check if it is indeed of type `char`? (`class(Time)`)

Comment: Everything is the same, except where Date and Time have c(), I switched it to point to the column in the data frame(I was just giving examples above, the org dataset is far to large to repro here). So the only change is  Date =  df$date Time =  df$time. To test if char, I used the class() function, and got:  "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

Comment: @rattacat OK I think I see the issue here. Before you ran my code, you must've already converted your `df$time` column to a `datetime` object. Although `gregexpr` automatically converts non-character objects to characters, this could be an issue if it does not know how to do the conversion. Can you try `Time = as.character(df$time)` and try again?

Comment: It worked like a charm- thank you so much for your help! really appreciated the gentle walkthu.